# How to properly initialize non-default-constructible class member?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, member

Assume I define a class `Foo`, which does not implement a default constructor.
In addition, I have a class `Bar`, which "owns" an instance of `Foo`:

```cpp
class Foo() {
  private:
    int m_member;
  public:
    Foo( int value ) : m_member(value) { }
};

class Bar() {
  private:
    Foo m_foo;
  public:
    Bar( /* ... */ ) {
      int something;
      /* lots of code to determine 'something' */
      /* should initialize m_foo to 'Foo(something)' here */
    }
};
```

The code as shown won't run, since `Bar` is trying to call the default constructor of `Foo`.

Now what I am trying to do is to have the constructor of `Bar` first determine `something` and then pass the result to the constructor of `Foo`.

One way to solve this is to have `Bar` only own a reference/pointer to `Foo` and initialize it after `m_something` was determined. However, I'd like to avoid that to make clear that the lifetime of `m_foo` is completely dependent on the lifetime of the owning class.

Another way would be to implement a default constructor in `Foo` and set the value later, which I would also like to avoid, since any instance of `Foo` should have a valid value for it's member (at any time).

What is the proper way to implement this? Am I stuck with a reference/pointer here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best idea will be to create helper function, that will calculate something and then just initialize `m_foo` in constructor initialized list.

```
class Bar {
  private:
    Foo m_foo;
  public:
    Bar( /* ... */ ) : m_foo(calculate_something()) {
    }
private:
    static int calculate_something()
    {
       int something = 0;
       // lot of code to calculate something
       return something;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also considered doing this, however in this case I would have to move a big part of the initialization of `Bar` to the helper function as well, because `something` depends on that.

Comment: @madmax1 bad. Then just calculate something independently, or use one of your ideas (pointer, or default constructible `Foo`).

Answer (score 2):

Does this complex initialization code actually *belong* to `Bar`? It may be good to consider having a *separate* class to just do this initializing. Something like

```
class Bar {
  public:
    Bar(int param, Foo foo): m_foo(foo) {
        // do just some very simple calculations, or use only constructor initialization list
    }
  ...
}

class BarBuilder {
  public:
    BarBuilder(/*...*/) {
        // do all calculations, boiling down to a few parameters for Bar and Foo
       Foo foo(fooParameter);
       m_result = new Bar(barParameter, foo); // give Foo here explicitly
    }
    Bar getResult() { return *m_result; }
  private:
    Bar* m_result; // or better use unique_ptr  
}
```

This also opens the way to a full Builder pattern that might be useful in case, for example, you do not always need all that complex calculations.

This assumes all classes to be copy-constructible, but you may more-or-less easily modify it to support what you need.